# Having all files of a project's bin folder copied to bin folder of referencing project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

One of my library projects contains a license file which I'm having copied to the `bin` folder by setting the file's `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer`.

Now, in one of my other projects which reference the first project, I want to have this license file copied, too. But I don't want to add a custom build step to the second project.

What is necessary to have dependent projects copy *all* files from a referenced project's `bin` folder?

### Edit:

VS Solution contains the following projects:

- Class Library #1  (= `CL1`)
- Class Library #2  (= `CL2`)
- Class Library #3  (= `CL3`)

`CL2` has a reference to `CL1`. `CL3` has a reference to `CL2`.

`CL1` contains a file that's supposed to be copied to the bin folder (e.g. `"ServerList.txt"`).

#### When I now build the solution (e.g. Debug configuration) ...

- `CL1\bin\Debug\` contains `"ServerList.txt"`
- `CL2\bin\Debug\` contains `"ServerList.txt"`
- `CL3\bin\Debug\` **does not contain** `"ServerList.txt"`

This is wrong!

#### Workaround:

If I add a reference to `CL1` to the `CL3` project, then `CL3\bin\Debug\` will also contain `"ServerList.txt"`.

However, this should not be necessary.

So, is this a bug? Or is this by design? Why should it make sense for Visual Studio not to copy everything from `CL2\bin\Debug\` when there is a reference to `CL2` in `CL3` alone?

Comment: That is the way the build process works.  So you can tell if a dll is newer in the source project from the build project you need to compare the dates of the two dlls.  Also you do not have to uses the new dll if you don't want to.  Connection to the source dll means that every time the source is rebuilt you are taking the latest version which may not be fully tested.  If you do not like the built -in options of the VS project you can always build using the command line compiler which gives more options.

Comment: If you want all users of your component to always get a license file, consider adding it to a [NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package).

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I may not have put my question clear, so I'd like to pose it another way. I amended my question accordingly.